# How to change/locate your website icon?

Tags: html, favicon

I am trying to change the icon from my website , there is another icon already present but it doesn't seem to change. I also can't locate where that icon is initialized in the first place.

this is what I added to my html page from favicon to change my icon :

```
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="icons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="icons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="icons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="icons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="icons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="icons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="icons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="icons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="icons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="icons/android-icon-192x192.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="icons/favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="icons/favicon-96x96.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="icons/favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="manifest" href="icons/manifest.json">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="icons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Even when i press shift+f5 to fully refresh my chrome page , it still displays the previous icon.

Comment: Try to clean your browser cache.

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, favicons are located at `/favicon.ico`. Also worth noting, browsers aggressively cache favicons because of how infrequently they change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code and can change your website icon.

```
<link rel="icon" href="new.gif" type="image/gif" sizes="20x20">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' href=path_to_icon />
```

It's size can be **16** or **24** pixels.

Browsers automatically locate icon in current directory as `favicon.ico` file.

Answer (score 0):

refreshing your web page won't work, you would need to rename the icon as it's cached on the web server/browser for quite a bit (since this isn't supposed to change).

Add a ?=v1.00 at the end of the favicon png, increment it every time the icon changes. This insures that the cache is invalidated and the client gets the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Try Below :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />
```